# printf shows wrong output, strange question mark at the end of line [C]

Tags: c, algorithm, queue

This code trying to perform queue, but that's queue has two fields: number and word. My problem is that field "word" prints incorrectly(field "number" is fine)

Expected output:

22
abc

12
efg

654
xyz

Unfortunately output looks like this

https://ibb.co/gjF446F

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <limits.h>
#include <string.h> 

#define MAX_capacity 1000
#define Max_len_napis 100


typedef struct{
   int number;
   char word[];

} data;

data intArray[MAX_capacity];
int peak = 0;
int rear = -1;
int itemCount = 0;

int front() {
   return intArray[peak].number;
}

bool isEmpty() {
   return itemCount == 0;
}

bool isFull() {
   return itemCount == MAX_capacity;
}

int size() {
   return itemCount;
}  

void insert(data x) {

   if(!isFull()) {

      if(rear == MAX_capacity-1) { 
         rear = -1;            
      }       

      int indeks = ++rear;
      intArray[indeks].number = x.number;
      strcpy (intArray[indeks].word, x.word);

      itemCount++;
   }
}


data remove() {
   data dat = intArray[peak++];

   if(peak == MAX_capacity) {
      peak = 0;
   }

   itemCount--;
   return dat;  
}


void print(int N){


    for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
        data n = remove();           
      printf("%d\n",n.number);
      printf("%s\n",n.word); // that's line doesn't work correctly




    }



}


int main() {
   data tab[3];

   tab[0].number = 22;
   strcpy (tab[0].word, "abc");
   insert(tab[0]);

   tab[1].number = 12;
   strcpy (tab[1].word, "efg");
   insert(tab[1]);

   tab[2].number = 654;
   strcpy (tab[2].word, "xyz");
   insert(tab[2]);



   int siz = size();
   print(siz);





    return 0;



   }
```

I think that printf("%s\n",n.word) is not work correctly. But if I dont use struct, all works properly.

Comment: `char word[];` reserves an array of zero chars. I'm sure that's not what you want.

Comment: `char word[]` is a flexible array member. You are supposed to allocate memory for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to allocate memory for word. For example like this:

```
typedef struct{
   int number;
   char word[100];

} data;
```

Better way is to allocate memory for word dynamically.

Comment: Thanks, its works! But why? What's the problem with word[]?

Comment: @Pawel, word[] allocates 0 bytes as soon as you don't initialize it. word[] is way to define flexible size array. "Flexible" doesn't mean array will automatically grow if you try to write more data into it. Flexible means compiler in case word[]="hello" will calculate length of the initialization string and allocate (6 bytes) required amount of memory.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <limits.h>
#include <string.h> 

#define MAX_capacity 1000
#define Max_len_napis 100


typedef struct{
   int number;
   char word[100];

} data;

data intArray[MAX_capacity];
int peak = 0;
int rear = -1;
int itemCount = 0;

int front() {
   return intArray[peak].number;
}

bool isEmpty() {
   return itemCount == 0;
}

bool isFull() {
   return itemCount == MAX_capacity;
}

int size() {
   return itemCount;
}  

void insert(data x) {

   if(!isFull()) {

      if(rear == MAX_capacity-1) { 
         rear = -1;            
      }       

      int indeks = ++rear;
      intArray[indeks].number = x.number;
      strcpy (intArray[indeks].word, x.word);

      itemCount++;
   }
}


data remove() {
   data dat = intArray[peak++];

   if(peak == MAX_capacity) {
      peak = 0;
   }

   itemCount--;
   return dat;  
}


void print(int N){


    for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
        data n = remove();           
      printf("%d\n",n.number);
      printf("%s\n",n.word); // that's line doesn't work correctly




    }



}


int main() {
   data tab[3];

   tab[0].number = 22;
   strcpy (tab[0].word, "abc");
   insert(tab[0]);

   tab[1].number = 12;
   strcpy (tab[1].word, "efg");
   insert(tab[1]);

   tab[2].number = 654;
   strcpy (tab[2].word, "xyz");
   insert(tab[2]);



   int siz = size();
   print(siz);





    return 0;



   }
```